# While loop for iterating all combinations between two values

Tags: python, while-loop

I want to create a loop that loads all  the iterations of two variables into a dataframe in seperate columns. I want variable "a" to hold values between 0 and 1 in 0.1 increments, and the same for variable "b". In otherwords there should be 100 iterations when complete, starting with 0 & 0, and ending with 1 & 1.

I've tried the following code

```
data = [['Decile 1', 10], ['Decile_2', 15], ['Decile_3', 14]]
staging_table = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Decile', 'Volume'])
profile_table = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['Decile', 'Volume'])

a = 0
b = 0

finished = False

while not finished:
    if b != 1:
        if a != 1:
            a = a + 0.1
            staging_table['CAM1_Modifier'] = a
            staging_table['CAM2_Modifier'] = b
            profile_table = profile_table.append(staging_table)
        else:
            b = b + 0.1
    else:
        finished = True  

profile_table
```

Comment: You never reset a. You should do so in the else clause. There is also no point separating the "b!=1" from the "finished" condition - put it directly into the while statement.

Comment: Yeah, that's it I think, I also had to make a < 1 rather than a != 1, but runs well now. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use itertools.product to get all the combinations:

```
import itertools
import pandas as pd

x = [i / 10 for i in range(11)]
df = pd.DataFrame(
    list(itertools.product(x, x)),
    columns=["a", "b"]
)

#        a    b
# 0    0.0  0.0
# 1    0.0  0.1
# 2    0.0  0.2
# ...  ...  ...
# 118  1.0  0.8
# 119  1.0  0.9
# 120  1.0  1.0
# 
# [121 rows x 2 columns]
```

Answer (score 1):

[`itertools`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html) is your friend.

```
from itertools import product

for a, b in product(map(lambda x: x / 10, range(10)),
                    map(lambda x: x / 10, range(10))):
  ...
```

`range(10)` gives us the integers from `0` to `10` (regrettably, `range` fails on floats). Then we divide those values by `10` to get your range from `0` to `1`. Then we take the Cartesian product of that iterable with itself to get every combination.